# Error PHP PDO: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

soy novato en PHP, y estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto, pero se me presentó el siguiente inconveniente:

> Mesa_2
> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cev\mesas\agregar.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Cev\mesas\agregar.php(23): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cev\mesas\agregar.php on line 23

**Código del error:**

```
<?php

//print_r($_POST);
if(empty($_POST["oculto"]) || empty($_POST["txtMesa"]))
{
    header('Location: agregarMesa.php?mensaje=camposVacios');
    exit();
}

include_once '../model/conexion.php';
$mesa= $_POST["txtMesa"];

print_r($mesa);

$sentencia= $bd->prepare("CREATE TABLE '?' (
    id INT(5) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombrePedido VARCHAR(100),
    precio DECIMAL(20,0),
    cantidad INT(11),
    total DECIMAL(20,0)
    )");
    
$resultado= $sentencia->execute([$mesa]);

if($resultado === TRUE)
{
    header('Location: newIndex.php?mensaje=agregado');
}

else
{
    header('Location: agregarPedido.php?mensaje=error');
    exit();
}
?>
```

**Código de donde se envía el dato:**

```
<?php

include_once "../model/conexion.php";
$sentencia= $bd -> query("SELECT nombre FROM mesas_disponibles");
$nombreMesa= $sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

?>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center" style="float:none;margin:auto;">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Añadir mesa:
                </div>

                <form class="p-4" method="POST" action="agregar.php">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <select class="form-control" name="txtMesa" autofocus>
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <?php
                            foreach($nombreMesa as $dato)
                            {
                            ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $dato->nombre ?>"><?php echo $dato->nombre ?></option>
                            <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-grid">
                        <input type="hidden" name="oculto" value="i">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Añadir">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Código de la conexión DB:**

```
<?php 

$contrasena= "";
$usuario= "root";
$nombre_db= "cevicheria";

try
{
    $bd= new PDO(
        'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$nombre_db,
        $usuario, 
        $contrasena, 
        array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES utf8")
    );
}catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo "Error de conexión: ".$e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

**Tabla "mesas_disponibles":**

[image: Tabla "mesas_disponibles"]

La verdad no entiendo por qué ocurre, solo estoy pasando un parámetro a la consulta. Espero puedan ayudarme, estaría muy agradecido.

Comment: Diria que los errores pueden ser dos:  1) En el prepare no encierres el `?` entre comillas simples, déjalo tal cual, a ver si cuela y 2) Si no cuela ponlo directamente como una variable `$mesa` y quítalo del execute.

Comment: Muchas gracias @masterguru , me funcionó la segunda solución de reemplazar el `?` por `$mesa`, llevaba días con algo tan simple, nuevamente te lo agradezco.

Comment: Perfecto, me alegro por ti. Me habias hecho dudar si el `?` era solo para valores de la consulta o bien se podia usar como una variable de sustitución en toda la consulta, pero si dices que no te ha funcionado entonces está claro que es solo para escapar los valores (y **no** como si fuera una variable de sustitución).

Comment: No puedes usar marcadores para identificadores (nombres de tablas o de columnas), pues los mismos son para vincular valores. Está explicado claramente en la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php): *Los marcadores de parámetros solamente pueden representar un literal de datos completo. No se pueden vincular usando parámetros una parte del literal, ni una palabra clave, **ni un identificador**, ni ninguna parte arbitraria de una consulta.* Por otra parte, suena extraño tener que crear tablas de forma dinámica. ¿Hay algo que justifique esa práctica?

Comment: @A.Cedano Estoy creando un sistema para restaurante, y lo que busco es registrar los pedidos de las mesas, modificarlos, eliminarlos y eso; así que se me ocurrió que cada mesa sea una tabla. Tal vez se pueda implementar de otra forma sin tablas dinámicas.

Comment: Crear tablas dinámicas no tiene sentido para el caso que expones, lo propio sería tener una tabla `mesa` en la cual registrarás una fila por cada cliente. Si cada vez creas una tabla, tendrás a lo largo del tiempo cientos o miles de tablas con una estructura similar y hacer algo tan sencillo como saber *la cantidad de clientes en el mes tal* o *la cantidad de veces que se pidió el plato tal el año pasado* será harto complicado, porque tendrás que recorrer tooooodas las tablas buscando esos datos, desaprovechando índices y demás.